# Events encapsulation provided C#?

Tags: c#, events

Can someone explain how Events provide encapsulation for accessing delegates other then the fact that you can't use the assignment `=` operator, but only `+=` and `-=`. The part I don't understand is this:

```
public delegate void CarEngineHandler(string msgForCaller);

public CarEngineHandler listOfHandlers;
```

If this is `public`, then we can do this `listOfHandlers.invoke("hello");`. This I get, however how do events provide encapsulation?

```
public events CarEngineHandler listOfHandlers;

listOfHandlers("hello"); //fire the event
```

Isn't firing the event and invoking call the delegates whenever you want? Where is the encapsulation?

Comment: Perhaps you can explain what _you_ mean by "encapsulation"?  Sounds like you're looking for "protection" or "hiding".

Answer (score 3):

`Events` can only be fired by the class that provided them. You can subscribe to a public event of a class, but can't fire it from a different class.

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8627sbea%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) on events.

Answer (score 0):

Events provide encapsulation by allowing responses to an event to happen outside of the object, while the object remains ignorant of that information.

```
class A
{
    private event Action _event;
    public event Action Event { add { _event += value; } remove { _event -= value; } }
    int counter = 0;
    public void AddOne()
    {
        counter++;
        if (counter > 0)
        {
            OnEvent();
        }
    }
    private void OnEvent()
    {
        if (_event != null)
            _event();
    }
}
class Program
{
    int Main()
    {
        string outsidestring = "THE CLASS HAS NO IDEA WHO I AM";
        A a = new A();

        a.Event += new Action(()=>Console.WriteLine(outsidestring));

        while (true)
        {
            Console.ReadLine();
            a.AddOne();
        }
    }
}
```

In this example, when A's counter hits 10 it can do something with the outsidestring without ever knowing anything about the outside string.